macOS associate filetype with executable
Using macOS (Sequoia) I want to associate a filetype with an executable. Not an application, a .command executable. Done it in the long past, so that a double click on the file ran the chosen executable with a single command line parameter, the file name. But all I can find now is how to associate a filetype with an application - but I don't want all that baggage, I just want to associate with an existing executable (of mine).

I'm not convinced that you can associate 'just' an executable. You might be able to use an intermediary, like an Automator workflow saved as an app, which passes the file onto your binary.
